# Event Handler Sequence is Not Consistent For Different Treeviews

Tags: excel, vba, treeview, mouseevent

I am working on an Excel VBA application that contains two treeview controls which are contained within a single user form.  The only difference between the two is that Treeview1 has two levels of nodes and Treeview2 has three levels.  Both treeviews utilize the same event handlers:

BeforeLabelEdit

MouseDown

MouseMove

NodeClick

OLEDragDrop

OLEDragOver

When the user mouseclicks a node in treeview1, the event sequence is MouseDown, then NodeClick.  However, for Treeview2 when the user clicks on a node, only
the NodeClick event gets triggered.  After some testing, I found that if I added the MouseUp event handler for treeview2, it triggers AFTER the NodeClick event. 
It appears the MouseDown event never gets triggered.

I'm wondering if anyone has run into a similar problem.  I can code around this, but I would really like to understand why this is happening. I assume there is something I'm not understanding about how event triggers get sequenced.

I'm using MouseDown to capture mouse & button selections and NodeClick to ID the selected node.  I initially used 
the MouseDown event handler to (1) capture key/button selects and (2) capture the selected node using the HitTest function.  However, hitTest wasn't 
capturing the correct node when I was testing my application on a different computer. It seemed easier to add the NodeClick eventHandler than try to code a generalized method for 
calculating/converting pixels across different computers.

The code is pretty complicated, so I have just included the MouseDown and NodeClick handlers for each treeview.

I am running Windows10, Version 1903 and Office 365 (16.0.12026.20344) 64-Bit.  I know that in the past there were issues with using the 
treeview controls in a 64-bit environment, so could this perhaps be related?

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
'=============================================================
'===== Event Handlers for Treeview 1 =========================
'=============================================================
Private Sub TreeView_LineItem_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As stdole.OLE_XPOS_PIXELS, ByVal y As stdole.OLE_YPOS_PIXELS)      
        gButton = Button
        gShift = Shift     
End Sub

Private Sub TreeView_LineItem_NodeClick(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)   
        Set gSelectedNode = Node
        If Not (gSelectedNode Is Nothing) Then
                If gShift = 0 Then
                        If gButton = 1 Then       'Left Mouse
                                Call Node_Enter(ControlPanel.TreeView_LineItem, gNodeCollLineItems, gNodeGraphLineItems, gSelectedNode)
                                Set prevSelectedNodeClick = gSelectedNode
                                Set prevSelectedNodeControl = Nothing
                                Set prevSelectedNodeShift = Nothing
                                ControlPanel.TreeView_LineItem.Refresh                                
                                If ControlPanel.Visible = False Then
                                        ControlPanel.Show vbModeless
                                End If       
                        ElseIf gButton = 2 Then   'Right Mouse
                                'Custom node selected for deletion
                                If gCustomLineItemDelete = True And gNumCustomLineItems > 1 Then
                                        Call DeleteCustomLineItemStep2(gSelectedNode, ControlPanel.TreeView_LineItem.Nodes)
                                        Application.Goto Reference:=wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
                                        gCustomLineItemDelete = False                                     
                                ElseIf gCustomLineItemModify = True And gNumCustomLineItems > 1 Then
                                        Call modifyCustomLineItemStep2(gSelectedNode, ControlPanel.TreeView_LineItem.Nodes)
                                        Application.Goto Reference:=wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
                                        gCustomLineItemModify = False                                                                      
                                        'Delete menu line item selected
                                ElseIf gCustomLineItemDelete = False Or gNumCustomLineItems = 1 Then
                                        If gNumCustomLineItems = 1 Then
                                                MsgBox "There are no custom line items"
                                        End If

                                        For Each cb In CommandBars
                                                If StrComp(cb.name, "LineItem") = 0 Then
                                                        cb.Delete
                                                End If
                                        Next

                                        If gCustomLineItemDelete = True Then
                                                GoTo endSub
                                        End If

                                        'Reset menu
                                        Set PopBar = CommandBars.Add(name:="LineItem", Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
                                        Set Top_Menu = PopBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=1, Temporary:=True)
                                        With Top_Menu
                                                .caption = "Clear LineItem Selections"
                                                .OnAction = "ClearLineItemCollections"
                                        End With


                                        PopBar.ShowPopup
                                End If
                        End If
                ElseIf gShift = 1 Then            'Shift
                        Call Node_Shift(ControlPanel.TreeView_LineItem, gNodeCollLineItems, gNodeGraphLineItems, gSelectedNode)
                        Set prevSelectedNodeShift = gSelectedNode
                        Set prevSelectedNodeControl = Nothing
                        Set prevSelectedNodeClick = Nothing
                        ControlPanel.TreeView_LineItem.Refresh
                        ControlPanel.Show vbModeless
                ElseIf gShift = 2 Then            'Cntl
                        Call Node_Control(ControlPanel.TreeView_LineItem, gNodeCollLineItems, gNodeGraphLineItems, gSelectedNode)
                        Set prevSelectedNodeControl = gSelectedNode
                        Set prevSelectedNodeClick = Nothing
                        Set prevSelectedNodeShift = Nothing
                        ControlPanel.TreeView_LineItem.Refresh                       
                        ControlPanel.Show vbModeless
                End If
        End If        
End Sub


'=============================================================
'===== Event Handlers for Treeview 2 =========================
'=============================================================
Private Sub TreeView_Segment_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal x As stdole.OLE_XPOS_PIXELS, ByVal y As stdole.OLE_YPOS_PIXELS)

  gShift = Shift
  gButton = Button       

End Sub

Private Sub TreeView_Segment_NodeClick(ByVal Node As MSComctlLib.Node)        
        set gSelectedNode = Node

        gShift = Shift
        gButton = Button

        If Not (gSelectedNode Is Nothing) Then
                If gShift = 0 Then
                        If gButton = 1 Then      'left mouse                                
                                Call Node_Enter(ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment, gNodeCollSegments, gNodeGraphSegments, gSelectedNode)
                                Set prevSelectedNodeClick = gSelectedNode
                                Set prevSelectedNodeControl = Nothing
                                Set prevSelectedNodeShift = Nothing
                                If ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment.SelectedItem <> gSelectedNode Then
                                        ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment.SelectedItem = gSelectedNode
                                        ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment.DropHighlight = gSelectedNode
                                End If
                                ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment.Refresh                               

                        ElseIf gButton = 2 Then  'Right Mouse
                                For Each cb In CommandBars
                                        If StrComp(cb.name, "Segment") = 0 Then
                                                cb.Delete
                                        End If
                                Next

                                Set PopBar = CommandBars.Add(name:="Segment", Position:=msoBarPopup, MenuBar:=False, Temporary:=True)
                                Set Top_Menu = PopBar.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=1, Temporary:=True)
                                With Top_Menu
                                        .caption = "Clear Segment Selections"
                                        .OnAction = "ClearSegmentCollections"
                                End With

                                PopBar.ShowPopup
                        End If
                ElseIf gShift = 1 Then           'Shift                       
                        Call Node_Shift(ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment, gNodeCollSegments, gNodeGraphSegments, gSelectedNode)
                        Set prevSelectedNodeShift = gSelectedNode
                        Set prevSelectedNodeControl = Nothing
                        Set prevSelectedNodeClick = Nothing
                        If ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment.SelectedItem <> gSelectedNode Then  
                                ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment.DropHighlight = Nothing  
                        End If
                        ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment.Refresh   
                        ControlPanel.Show vbModeless
                ElseIf gShift = 2 Then           'Cntl              
                        Call Node_Control(ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment, gNodeCollSegments, gNodeGraphSegments, gSelectedNode)
                        Set prevSelectedNodeControl = gSelectedNode
                        Set prevSelectedNodeClick = Nothing
                        Set prevSelectedNodeShift = Nothing
                        If ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment.SelectedItem <> gSelectedNode Then
                                ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment.SelectedItem = gSelectedNode
                        End If
                        ControlPanel.TreeView_Segment.Refresh                       
                        ControlPanel.Show vbModeless
                End If
        End If

endSub:
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried setting up 2 simple treeviews on a new form and mousedown worked fine for me in that simpler environment - in case that helps

Comment: Thanks.  I think it may be related to whether or not the control has focus.  I was having a similar problem elsewhere in the program and when I explicitly set the focus back to the treeview things worked OK.